# What's the difference between /anaconda3/bin/python and /anaconda3/bin/python3?

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to use python, but it doesn't recognize parenthesis-free print statements. Apparently "which python" shows this path:

/anaconda3/bin/python

and "which python3" shows

/anaconda3/bin/python3

What is the first one used for, if it's not python2?

Comment: @Carcigenicate No, I just have python2 code I want to execute in Anaconda3, but I also wonder why there are two python executables in Anaconda3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are basically the same. It's just that some scripts may explicitly call `python3`, while others are less touchy and simply call `python`. So the Python 3 interpreter is installed with both names.

In a Python 2 environment, you'd see `python2` and `python`, but not `python3`. And outside of conda environments, an operating system or other Python installation may provide `python3`, `python2` and `python`, where the administrator decides whether `python` maps to one or the other.